# Autonumber fields on standard objects are not packageable. Any workaround for this. Please suggest

Tags: package, unmanaged-package

I tried to create a `unmanaged package` and got this error when i tried to upload. Is there any workaround for this. I have already googled and did not find any solid article for this issue. Please suggest.

> Autonumber fields on standard objects are not packageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently looks like it is a limitation..

Check this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqC8AAK

If you want deploy an auto-number field between sandboxes? then change field datatype from Auto Number to Text then revert the change after migration complete.